# requestReview() doesn't show the rating prompt on iOS14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I tried to run the following code in viewDidLoad(), if I build and run it from Xcode, the app can show the rating prompt correctly, but if I run the app on my iPhone manually, then the rating prompt doesn't show. Why is that?

My system is: iOS 14.4.1, Xcode 12.4

```
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
                    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
                }
            } else if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
                SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
    }
```

Also, if I just place this line of code in viewDidLoad(), then I don't have this issue:

`SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()`

Comment: Just a guess but perhaps `$0.activationState == .foregroundActive` is failing. Try this in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @strangetimes , so why it has no issue if I run it from Xcode directly?

Comment: You should always test on the device as it may result in a different experience, especially when it comes to requesting for reviews.

Comment: @strangetimes , I am testing on real device, I mean after I installed the app on the real device, if I tap it to run it manually, it has this issue.  But, if I build and run it from Xcode to the real device,  it has no issue.

Comment: The answer below is correct - when running from Xcode it would assume you’re actively debugging. When launching otherwise, normal limits will be in place so you won’t see the prompt more than a couple of times a month.

Comment: @strangetimes , No, if I use "SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()" only, it has no issue and I can see the prompt every time I run the app.

Comment: As I said, you should try viewDidAppear as the scene may not have connected on the actual device in viewDidLoad. Does that work?

Comment: viewDidLoad, you will later find, is also a troublesome place where many of the safe area constraints aren’t available until the view is about to appear.

Comment: @strangetimes , yes, viewDidAppear works. But, why viewDidLoad would work if I run it from Xcode?

Comment: Also, viewDidAppear is not ideal for me, since the prompt will show every time the view appear.

Comment: Because the simulator is not reliable. You should always test on the real device, which will behave differently at times. Especially, on the simulator the viewDidLoad works most of the times but on device the view does not in fact connect to the scene or the window until viewWillAppear.

Comment: @strangetimes , No!  It seems you didn't understand my question. I never tested it on simulator.  I mean I run the app by pressing CMD+R on Xcode to run it on the iPhone, then the prompt always show.  But if I tap and run the app manually on iPhone, the prompt doesn't show.

Comment: Either way, looks like the behavior is different when launching on its own. viewDidLoad is not reliable a place to be showing another VC from. You could also get away with viewWillAppear.